# Inherit from parent class and form, then I want a listview

Tags: django

I have a model form

```
class Parent(forms.ModelForm):
    someTest = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I have a child form:

```
class Child(Parent):
    someTestChild = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I want a listview for the child form, this is my url.py

```
path('Testing/', 
views.Child.as_view(),name="child"),
```

but I get an error saying that this class has no .as_view possibility.
Is it possible to create an list and detailview on the child form.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `as_view()` on the `forms.ModelForm` class which is not possible. You can only call that on a Class-Based View. Also, do you even have a model created that you can use for the form and view?

Consult the following docs for an example ListView (and also check the docs about models if you don't have any yet): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

Note the difference between a view and a form in general:

```py
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

from articles.models import Article

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do is show a model that you have inherited from in your forms.ModelForms. In that case you could just create the model you want to show in your models.py. Then in your forms.py add:

```
from .models import YourModel

class FormName(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

after that you can use the form you have created in your html by connecting it via your views.py:

```
from .forms import FormName

def form_page(request):
    my_form = FormName()

if request.method == 'POST':
    my_form = FormName(request.POST)

    if my_form.is_valid():
        my_form.save(commit=True)
    else:
        print('Error Form could not be read')

return render(request, 'path_to/my.html', {'my_form': my_form})
```

now you can insert the form in your html file by using:

```
    <form method="POST">
        {{ my_form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
    </form>
```

The .as_p at the end will make your form look nicer on the webpage.
Be sure to include the csrf_token otherwise it will not work.
Also keep in mind if you want to upload and include images into your model there are a few extra lines of code necessary to make it work.

Now that you have the form in your html to show the models created with the form you will need to first connect the model to your view:

```
def index(request):
model_items = MyModel.objects.all()
context = {
    'model_items': model_items
}
return render(request, "home/index.html", context=context)
```

then include them in the html where you want to show them. You can easily use for loops to integrate them into your code. For example:

```
<table>
{% for item in model_items %}
<tr>
    <td>
        {{ item.property_nr_one }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ item.property_nr_two }}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: tx, but i want to use the (Listview) and (Detailview), you are right i have a model which has a parrent model. In forms.py i created both forms, and in html i want the listview of the childform (and thus the fields of the parrent).

Comment: im not sure I fully understand but wouldn't the form be the child of the model in that case? When using forms.ModelForms is it not to quickly make a premade model into a form understandable for html. Also if you want to use .as_view() im pretty sure you still have to make a view in your views.py